# How do I select and update just the name values from this map in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a set of documents of the type:

```
contactId: V123132,
{
    "accessMap": {
      "136400": [
        "STANDARD"
      ],
      "136401": [
        "STANDARD"
      ],
      "136535": [
        "STANDARD"
      ],
      "136672": [
        "RG0763",
        "ADMIN",
        "STANDARD"
      ],
      "136676": [
        "RG0763",
        "ADMIN",
        "STANDARD"
      ]
    }
  },
"documentType": "ACS_MAP"
```

I want to update the keys of the accessMap and append a ":2" at the end of each key in the `accessMap`,I'm trying to figure out how to write query for that.

What I've done so far is to select the keys of the accessMap I did a:

`SELECT OBJECT_NAMES(`contact-services`.accessMap) from` contact-services `where documentType = "ACS_MAP"`

which gives me:

```
{
    "$1": [
      "136400",
      "136401",
      "136535",
      "136672",
      "136676"
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach for it..?

Comment: Can you give of an example of what/how you want to change them? Do you plan on adding values to those arrays, removing values, changing values, etc?

Comment: Sure, if there is a number, "123", I want to append ":2" at the end of it.

Comment: check out updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change values you need to use UPDATE statement.
UPDATE statement LHS of SET/UNSET needs path, so you need to aware of the path you want to update.
You have ARRAY you can use any ARRAY functions https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html or construct new ARRAY

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET d.accessMap.`136672` = ARRAY_APPENED(d.accessMap.`136672`,"xyz")
WHERE ......;

UPDATE default AS d  
SET d.accessMap.[v] = ARRAY_APPEND(d.accessMap.[v], "hello") 
               FOR v IN OBJECT_NAMES(d.accessMap) 
               WHEN v IN ["136672", "136676"] END 
WHERE ....;
```

post fix ":2" every key of accessMap. If need specific pattern use CASE expression.

```
UPDATE default AS d  
SET d.accessMap = OBJECT (v.name|| ":2") : v.val FOR v IN OBJECT_PAIRS(d.accessMap) END 
WHERE ....;
```